# Why is echo printing past the quotations?

Tags: php, html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<body>
<?php

//printing
echo "<p>Hello, World</p>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is suppose to be a basic hello world example but when I run it in the browser I get an extra "; ?>

```
Hello, World

"; ?>
```

Why is that?

EDIT: Yes the file extension is php

EDIT2: I created the file with Notepadd++. I ran the file by right clicking the file and open with chrome.

EDIT3: Okay so what I gathered is that I can't just run the file locally. I will try through a web server. Thank you for the responses so far!

Comment: is this a php file? or an html file? change it to `yourfile.php`

Comment: Likely none of your PHP is getting executed at all.

Comment: it is a php file extension

Comment: Is it running on an apache webserver or locally? Does phpinfo(); work?

Comment: How are you accessing the page? What URL? Do you have a webserver with php set up?

Comment: You might be running in an `.html` file instead of `.php` file

Comment: I literally created a php in Notepad++ and opened the file in my chrome browser.

Comment: "I created the file with Notepadd++. I ran the file by right clicking the file and open with chrome." is pointing your problem.

Comment: So according to the second edit, you simply don't run it in the web server but as a local HTML file. See nl-x's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is that you do not have a local server such as [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html).

I would suggest downloading xampp and then follow the instructions for running a php file.

Make sure you have .php as the file extension

Comment: This one will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not running your file through your web server, but you are opening it locally.

Make sure your url is something like `http://localhost/myFile.php`. And not `c:\documents and settings\myName\Desktop\myFile.php`.

Answer (score 1):

> "I created the file with Notepadd++. I ran the file by right clicking
>   the file and open with chrome."

You are saying your problem. PHP files are not like HTML files. They must be compiled before served.

For example:

```
<html><body><?php echo date("Y"); ?><body><html>
```

will be expected to show the system year. If you try to open it browser does not recognize PHP scripts and treats that function as a text and you see

```
echo date("Y"); ?>
```

Why don't you see `<?php` ? Because after `<`character, the browser thinks that there is an HTML tag coming.

If you run that PHP file correctly and then look at the source HTML you will see

```
<html><body>2014<body><html>
```

You must move the file to web server directory like `c:\xampp\www` or to `c:\wamp\www`.

Then run apache server.

After that open a browser window and type `localhost/yourfile.php:80`

`80` could vary in according to your settings (Take a look at `httpd.conf` file).